# FFMPEG libavformat internal buffering

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, libavformat

I'm using FFMPEG for a C++ audio streaming and playback application.

I use the **avformat_open_input** function to open an URL to an external compressed audio file and then I step through to stream using **av_read_frame**. Then for each packet i directly decode the data and queue it in the audio buffer using OpenAL.

My question is if FFMPEG internally prebuffers compressed data from the external URL?

Does FFMPEG keep downloading data in the background even if I don't call **av_read_frame**?

Or is it my responsibility to maintain a intermediate buffer where I download as many packets as possible ahead of time to avoid starving the audio-playback?

If so, how much does it buffer/download internally? Can I configure this?

I have been looking through the documentation but have not found any information on this.

Thanks.

Update:
According to this thread http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=376 libav should by default prebuffer about 5MB depending on AVFormatContext::max_analyze_duration.  However I haven't noticed this behavior and it doesn't seem to change if I alter max_analyze_duration.

If I monitor the memory consumption of my process it doesn't increase after I call avformat_open_input and if I simulate slow-network, av_read_frame directly stops working like if it didn't have any packets buffered.